# Linear Algebra Matlab matrix loop?

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm new to both linear algebra and Matlab, so naturally I'm probably asking an obvious question. If someone could attempt to explain to me in layman's terms how to go about answering this question in Matlab it'd be great, thanks in advance.

[image: Question]

Comment: how new are you to matlab?

Comment: This September was the first time I've used it, other than this my only other coding experience is some html webpage writing

Answer (score -2):

Loops are for suckers.

`function x_new = matrix_recursion(A, endp, x_start)
 if (endp == 0)
  x_new = x_start
 else
  x_new = matrix_recursion(A, endp-1, A*x_start);
 end`

I don't have MatLab on this computer so I can't test it, but it should work fine.

Comment: it actually didn't, got an error about how function is not permitted

Comment: What exactly did it say?

Comment: function x_new = matrix_recursion(A, end, x_start)
 |
Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this
context.

Comment: Are you entering it in the interactive shell? This is supposed to be saved as a script matrix_recursion.m and then run

Comment: I just noticed a couple mistakes and edited my answer accordingly. Try it now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by the interactive shell and saving it as a script matrix_recursion.m

Comment: The place where it has the >> on every line and does every command as soon as you press enter is called a shell. You need to save the code in a file called "matrix_recursion.m", then type (for instance) "matrix_recursion([1,0;0,1], 25, [0;1])" into the shell. The first parameter should be the matrix that you actually want to use for A, I put it [1,0;0,1] as an example. If that doesn't work try deleting the entire first line (with the %) and try saving and running it again.